# Full width and height on any screen size

Tags: css

I know this is quite a simple question but I am a beginner. I am looking for a tutorial which can teach me how to code a design such as this one: http://dsp.io/. Can anybody recommend me one?

I want to know how to make it take up the entire browser's window, regardless of what size the screen on which you view the website is.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called Fluid Design.

If you are a beginner, try to use Bootstrap.

Check this reference link

http://bootply.com/60257

Fluid grid system will change as Mobile template if you zoom the browser, and expands automatically if you zoom out filling the entire screen.

Bootstrap 3 is released. Check out that!

Hope this helps, comment if any doubt.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will use bootply to guide me in creating the code for my design.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll have a tutorial on how to make a responsive website: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-basic-responsive-site-css

Basically, you'll have to wrap everything within the `<body> </body>` tags into a #wrapper, like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

and set the width to 100% in your css file, like this

```
#wrapper {width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you've mentioned doesn't have "full width and height", otherwise it wouldn't be scrollable; this is just 100% width.

If you want full width and height, though, you just have to create a wrapper div and set those properties to 100%:

```
#wrapper
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then remove undesired margins and paddings from the page:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This is **very** basic stuff, you should really study and search more before asking questions. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started)'s a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great book on [Responsive Design by Ethan Marcotte](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). You can read it to understand how to make a resposive site.